iOS 18 beta simulator doesn't work with FaceID: CoreAuthUl quit unexpectedly
With iOS 18 beta the FaceID authentication is not working for us in simulator context.
It's crashing the Simulator, see:

However with a real device on iOS 18 beta the biometry prompt appears and works as expected.
Interestingly on iOS 18 beta 6 simulator with TouchID (iPhone SE 3rd gen.) everything is fine, so the bug is limited to FaceID simulators only.
Is there anyone else experiencing this issue?
Did you find a workaround for this?

I'm experiencing the same thing on simulator iPhone 15 Pro Max  with iOS 18 beta 6 (it was also happening in previous beta versions); but haven't found a workaround yet. Tried enabling/disabling FaceID from the simulator settings but to no avail.

Same happens on Xcode 16 RC

I filed a radar with Apple. Please file it too. https://openradar.appspot.com/FB15120391

Can someone check if the issue is also present if Xcode is being run on MacOS Sequoia?

Yes, final version of Xcode 16 on macOS 15 Sequoia still behaves the same for me.

The problem seems to be fixed in iOS 18.1 Simulators (Xcode 16.1 beta 2). (Without any mention in Release Notes). But not in earlier Simulators.
